# JS ES6: How to give child methods access to their sibblings?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have multiple utility methods like

```js
export const makeTextUtils = ({ U }) =>
  Object.freeze({
    hello: () => "Hello World!",
    lorem: () => "Lorem ipsum..."
  )};
```

these child utils can reference each other

```js
export const makeOutputUtils = ({ U }) =>
  Object.freeze({
    logHello: () => console.log(U.txt.hello())
  )};
```

Now I want to expose the Utils in a utils.js and **inject the parent Method into all children**

```js
import { makeTextUtils } from './text';
import { makeOutputUtils } from './output';

// dependency injections
const textUtils = makeTextUtils({ U });
const outputUtils = makeTextUtils({ U });

// building parent util method
export const U = Object.freeze({
  txt: textUtils,
  out: outputUtils
});
```

I've tried various ways of importing the U at the top of the main file and switching up the order within the file, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare the `U` object at the top so that you can pass it down to the other functions. Then, after U gets properties assigned to it, you can freeze it:

```
import { makeTextUtils } from "./text";
import { makeOutputUtils } from "./output";

export const U = {};

// dependency injections
const textUtils = makeTextUtils({ U });
const outputUtils = makeOutputUtils({ U });

// building parent util method
Object.assign(U, {
  txt: textUtils,
  out: outputUtils
});
Object.freeze(U);

U.out.logHello();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-benz-cu3n5

The passing of `U` inside an object and immediately destructuring it in the utility functions doesn't seem to do anything - unless there's a particular reason for that, feel free to just pass the `U` object alone (and to use the `U` parameter alone).